# MVC3 : How to force empty field to update as 0 during UpdateModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

***UPDATE:** Part of the reason for this question could be traced back to bad database design. I had allowed myself to be talked into a design that in turn led to poor choices for a UI design. I decided to go back and refactor the DB design, which removed the problem on the UI. Therefore, this question is moot and I won't be accepting an answer. I can't delete the question because there are already answers and comments.*

Is there anyway to cause MVC3 / EF to treat an empty form field as a zero? That is, if the user leaves a certain field blank, or blanks out a certain field, I want EF to treat that as a zero, and not as a null value.

I know how to make this work with string fields using data annotations, but I can't make it work with integer fields.

I hope this question makes sense. I've been fiddling with data annotations, custom validators, blah blah blah, all morning and I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: I think you should still accept an answer that would solve the problem, even though you don't have the problem yourself anymore. This will make it easier for anyone who comes here looking for an answer to the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of work around.You can make the input field to zero if it is empty before posting form data when user clicks the submit button in your form . You can use JavaScript to do this

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I figured I could do something like that, I was just wondering how to do this with the MVC/EF tools.

Comment: Jayantha, maybe you could post some code illustrating your suggestion for anyone who lands here looking for a similar solution.

Answer (score 3):

don't make the integer a nullable type. If you just use plain old `int`, it will automatically be zero unless you set it to something else.

Use: `int` instead of `int?`

Comment: The field is not nullable. The problem is when the user leaves the field blank, I want MVC / EF to treat that as a zero, but instead it is treating it as a null value, which is not a valid value.

Comment: no. I have nothing in my metadata class relating to that particular field. It is marked as "IsNullable=false" in the edmx, and I have set the default value to 0 in the edmx as well.